# c# Authenticating Soap web service with windows authentication

Tags: c#, soap

I have a soap service which uses Active Directory (Windows authentication). I know how to simply pass a username and password as network credentials. But how to implement automatic authentication like for example Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio uses where you can choose Windows authentication and the current logged in user is authenticated automatically without the need of typing in a domain\username or password.

```
var server = new MySoapClient();

if (server.ClientCredentials != null)
{
    server.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = 
           new NetworkCredential("MyUsername", "MyPassword");
}

server.MyMethod();
```

I do not know how to pass the user currently logged into Windows to the Soap service.

Comment: Have a look at [Transport security with Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-windows-authentication).